# RaspberryPi Apache and Symbolic Link

Tags: apache, proftpd

I can't see my symbolic link in apache and ftp(proftpd).

My symbolic link on HDD is: `/media/hrc1tb/Film-Dizi`

```
/media/hrc1tb/Film-Dizi 
Permissions: [permissions][1]
```

My apache and ftp folder is `/home/pi/www/html/film` and this is my
`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: /etc/rc.local file: ln -s /media/hrc1tb/Film-Dizi /home/pi/www/html/film

Comment: /media/hrc1tb/Film-Dizi Permissions: https://ibb.co/cMXbo8